# Compare HttpContext with Boolean i

Tags: c#, .net-core

In my middleware in the .NET core app, I've use the `HttpContext` to save the value of the cookie, as below:

```
app.Run(async context =>
{
    //  context.Response.Cookies.Append("se_id","5"); 
    if(context.Request.Cookies["se_id"] == 5){
     context.Items["isVerified"] = true;
    }

    await _next.Invoke(context);  
});
```

Then in the function, i'm trying to check it using:

```
bool v = HttpContext.Items["isVerified"]  == true;
if (v){
      Console.WriteLine("Verified request? {0}", HttpContext.Items["isVerified"]);
     }
else{
     Console.WriteLine("NOT Verified request? {0}", HttpContext.Items["isVerified"]);
}
```

It gave me the compilation error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'bool' [netcoreapp1.1] Gets the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext for the executing action. HttpContext ControllerBase.HttpContext

I can solve it by redefining it in the middleware I defined it as:

```
context.Items["isVerified"] = "true";
```

then check it in the function by:

```
bool v = HttpContext.Items["isVerified"].ToString()  == "true";
```

Is there a way to avoid use it as `Boolean` instead of being forced to convert it to `text` in both sides.

Comment: have you tried casting "isVerified" to Boolean first? like `((bool)HttpContext.Items["isVerified"])  == true;`

Comment: @th1rdey3 just tried it, if itis `NULL` it is not converted to `bool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use it like so:

```
if ((bool)HttpContext.Items["isVerified"])
    Console.WriteLine("Verified request? {0}", HttpContext.Items["isVerified"]);
else
    Console.WriteLine("NOT Verified request? {0}", HttpContext.Items["isVerified"]);
```

But keep in mind that this will not protect you against null ref exception if `HttpContext.Items["isVerified"]` is `null`

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer, and provided what I found considering your feedback in a different answer.